# Plot clusters from LDA Gensim with Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, vectorization, gensim, dimensionality-reduction

I apologise in advance as I cannot reproduce the dataset I'm working with. So I am just going to describe steps and hope someone is familiar with the whole process.

I'm trying to use LDA Gensim to extract topics from a list of text documents.

```
from gensim.models import LdaModel
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
```

I build `dictionary` and `corpus`:

```
dictionary = Dictionary(final_docs)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in final_docs]
```

where `final_docs` is a list of lists with cleaned tokens for each text like this:

```
final_docs = [['cat','dog','animal'],['school','university','education'],...['music','dj','pop']]
```

then I initiate the model like this:

```
# Set training parameters:
num_topics = 60
chunksize = 100
passes = 20
iterations = 400
eval_every = None 

# Make an index to word dictionary
temp = dictionary[0]  # This is only to "load" the dictionary.
id2word = dictionary.id2token

model = LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=id2word, chunksize=chunksize, \
                           alpha='auto', eta='auto', \
                           iterations=iterations, num_topics=num_topics, \
                           passes=passes, eval_every=eval_every)
```

I can print topics and terms (10 most important). And they make sense. So it seems working fine.

```
for idx in range(n_topics):
    print("Topic #%s:" % idx, model.print_topic(idx, 10))
```

BUT I struggle to plot all the documents as clusters using Bokeh. (And I really need Bokeh because I compare the same plot from different models). I know I have to reduce dimensionality to 2. And I try to do it using CountVectorizer and then T-sne:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
docs_vect = [' '.join(txt) for txt in final_docs]
cvectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=6, max_df=0.50, max_features=10000, stop_words=stop)
cvz = cvectorizer.fit_transform(docs_vect)
X_lda = model.fit_transform(cvz)
```

But I get this error: `AttributeError: 'LdaModel' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'`
I'm definitely doing something wrong with CountVectorizer. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Your use of CountVectorizer looks fine, but you are calling `fit_transform` on `model`, which is a `gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel` object. As your error says, there is no such method for this object (or in the whole of gensim AFAIK).

Comment: I just saw that there is a `sklearn` [wrapper in gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/ldamodel.html) that actually does have a `fit_transform`. Maybe take a look at that.